# How can you use Vue + Router alongside an API in node

Tags: javascript, api, express, vuejs2

I have a Vue page to make, and I want to use Vue Router. However, I also need to have one page act as an API route (for legacy reasons).

Basically, I need one particular route to work as an API (Does some work, looks at some non-public databases, returns some odd XML), running on the same port as a Vue + Router single page application.

There are lots of tutorials on how to use Vue + Router, but I don't understand *how* it works behind the scenes. I'm guessing there's a way to make an express app that maps '/api' to a basic route handler, and '/app' to a webapp, but vue + router seems to be built around vue getting its own port.

How do I get Vue router and an API running on the same port?

Comment: does express serve your built app? if so you can use middleware, so if the express route doesn't exist, it load index.html which then vue router takes over

Comment: I'm making it from the ground up, so I can use anything. Will this work with the vue-cli plugins? Auth0, in particular, is the one I'm worried about.

Comment: Maybe vue-cli isn't felxible enough for this. I'll try setting up something without it.

Comment: In your express just serve the dist folder `app.use('/', express.static('../path/to/dist')`, any routes after like `/api` will not conflict if they exist, express will serve it, if not as said use a fallback to vues index.html to handle the error (if you even need it)

Comment: That makes sense, but I was using vue-cli, so that wouldn't work. I'm going to try putting the vue page and express api in different projects, with a proxy server redirecting to each of them as needed. The proxy server shouldn't be too hard, and the vue page and api are pretty different anyway.

Comment: Incidentally, I found a page that explains how to do exactly what I want, but I'm not sure it's clean code. https://dennisreimann.de/articles/vue-cli-serve-express.html

Comment: yeah I like to keep them split, though you could use [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) to start both and join both project via package.json, I was making a codesandbox example, but give up as codesandbox upload seems broke and dont feel inclined to setup git repo for it.

Comment: That's looks cool

Comment: yeah your link looks like another way instead of using multiple processes whilst developing, got codesandbox working after a struggle https://codesandbox.io/s/app-xu6oz